# Why is it saying no arguments given

Tags: java

Here is my code. I think the error is coming from the fight() method. It is supposed to use whatever the attack is given EX. "#" and print that for the number of levels like this "attack=#, level=5" and it would print "#####"

```
public class Dragon 
{
    private String attack;
    private int level;

    public Dragon (int level, String attack)
    {
        this.level = level;
        this.attack = attack;

    }
    public String getAttack()
    {
        return attack;
    }
    public int getLevel()
    {
        return level;
    }

    // Put other methods here
    private void fight(int level, String attack)
    {
        if (level < 0)
        {
            System.out.print(attack);
        }
    }

    // String representation of the object
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Dragon is at level " + level + " and attacks with " + attack;
    }
}
```

```
Grader.java: Line 57: Method is expecting type int, String and type "no arguments" was given.
```

Comment: what was in line 57 of your code?

Comment: @Mukit09 I am using codeHs as a practice website and it will not let me see the grader so I'm not sure

Comment: where are you using `Grader` class??? is this the only file you have??

Answer (score -1):

You are saying you don't have access to the Grader class...

Maybe the fight method doesn't need any arguments? 
Looks like the constructor is already setting those variables.

Remove the arguments from your flight method and check for this.level < 0 instead?

Comment: how is the method `fight` have any relation to the `Grader` class , also his code is symantically correct

Comment: I think you may be right. They may have to use `this.level` and `this.attack` in a `fight()` method.

Comment: I was thinking the Grader class instantiates a Dragon object. At which point, level and attack will be set as there is only one constructor.
It then calls fight method, so it would be redundant to also pass in the parameters there if they are already set using the constructor. 
I'm speculating. OP didn't answer me.